Get App current version from Play/Apple Store
I'm developing a feature inside my application that requires the user to always have the latest version before logging into the platform.
As my client requested, the user will also always need internet connection to access. So, this point shouldn't be a problem.
I know that this Nugget Package allows to get In App Updates from Google Play Store, but I'm not finding any information about something like this from Apple Store.
Is there any resource that I can use to retrieve this information? I don't want to maintain a new API to check the current app version x installed version everytime a new user uses the app. (But I'm not excluding this idea)

I wouldn't use the store information, because there may be different versions available on different release channels and for different device types. You also don't have a link to the backend then. A common way of doing this is having an endpoint that serves as a health check and which also sends version information. For example, the backend could provide a "MinimumAppVersion" : "1.2.3" property in the response. You can then compare this to the locally installed version and then take a decision, e.g. allow sign-in or request an update.
